# Java Swing Timer Actionperformed doesn't get called

Tags: java, swing, timer

So, I've been messing around with the Swing Timer in Java, trying to make a little time counter. However, the actionperformed method doesn't seem to react whenever I make a timer and let it run.
Here's my simplified UI class:

```
public class UI implements ActionListener {

    private int value = 0;
    Timer timer = new Timer(5,this);

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        value++;
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

And this is what my launcher looks like:

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UI ui = new UI();
        ui.start();
    }

}
```

When I run the launcher, nothing happens. I do know he creates the UI and lets the timer start, but the timer doesn't seem to call the Actionperformed method.
I'm wondering why.
It should show the value +1 every interval of 5 (miliseconds?).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Simplified my code, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use a `javax.swing.Timer` outside of the Swing context, that is most likely the source of your problem. Try using a `java.util.Timer` instead.

Comment: ammoQ, make your comment an answer and I will accept it. With a tiny bit of research on how util.Timer works, I managed to get it working :D
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Your program is exiting before the timer Thread has a chance to start. You should give a little time before exiting the main Thread to allow the timer Thread to keep running. `Thread.sleep(100)` after `ui.start()`should solve.

Comment: If I hadn't used a swing timer instead of util timer, this would have been a possible solution for sure. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

hey i can help you out... you should do the following ;

firstly import the following ;

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent ;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener ;

import javax.swing.Timer ;
```

then initialize the timer at the end of the form like this ;
public static void main(String args[]) {

```
     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {        
                public void run() {       
                new mainprogramme().setVisible(true);    
            }    


  });    

    }    
        private Timer timer ;
```

then after initializing the timer add a public class like following;

```
public class progress implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

    int n = 0 ;
    if (n<100){
        n++ ;
        System.out.println(n) ;
    }else{
        timer.stop() ;
    }
    }
    }
```

after you do this go to the j Frame>right click and select>Events>window>window Opened and type the following ;

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        timer = new Timer(100,new progress()) ;
```

and after you do all this take a button name it as anything and type the following in its void like following ;

```
  timer.start();
```

AND THAT'S IT CODE IT AND THEN REPLY ME...